# ActiveRecord exists? with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following ActiveRecord call:

```
@payment = account.business.payments.find(params[:id])
```

Which searches through associations for a `payment` with id of `params[:id]`. However, this throws a RecordNotFound exception.

I'd like to call `exists?` instead to see if the record exists to avoid throwing an exception. Doing `Payment.exists?(account.business.payments.find(params[:id]))` does not work.

I'd like to search only the `payments` that `belong_to` that `business`, and not all payments by doing `Payment.exists?(:id => params[:id])`. That is so I can know that it's that particular account's business's payment.

How can I do that?

Note:
`account` has_one `business` and `business` has_many `payments`.

Comment: since you are looking for an id, can't you use `Payment.find(params[:id])` rather than having that really long path?

Comment: @sircapsalot: The OP may want to limit the scope for security reasons...

Comment: @PinnyM That's the reason.

Comment: @PinnyM makes sense, thanks! - i'm still pretty new with rails :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `where` instead of `find`, it will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` representing 0 or more records, off of which you can chain `.exists?`:

```
@payments = account.business.payments.where(id: params[:id])


if @payments.exists?
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to check for existence:

```
account.business.payments.where(:id => params[:id]).exists?
```

If you plan on using this record, then call `.first` instead of  `exists?` since only 1 record is expected. Incidentally, you can also do this using dynamic finders (which are deprecated in Rails 4):

```
account.business.payments.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

This will return `nil` if no record exists (instead of blowing up).

Comment: Instead of the dynamic finder you can use `account.business.payments.where(:id => params[:id]).first`

Comment: @WizardofOgz: that was the first solution (where I recommend using `.first` if the record will actually be used).

Comment: whoops, sorry, I really didn't read your answer right the first time. I had upvoted it anyway ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that using `present?` force ActiveRecord to load whole collection from database, which obviously is not always ideal:

```
user.posts.present?
=>  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1 ORDER BY `sales`.`id` ASC
```

If you want to check if collection exists in database and you don't need data then use `any?`

```
user.posts.any?
=> SELECT 1 AS one FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Also `exists?` without any arguments works the same as `any?`

```
user.posts.exists?
=> SELECT 1 AS one FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1
```

But you can do much more with this one: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F

Answer (score 0):

Someone can overrule if I'm wrong, but I would suggest

```
account.business.payments.where(:id => params[:id]).pluck(:id).present?
```

By doing a pluck you are skipping instantiation of the associated objects.  This means that they don't have to be loaded into memory which will save some cycles if you are doing this a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use your association for exists?

```
Business.find(business_id).payments.exists?(payment_id)
```

This should return true if the payment exists in that business.